# Visual Studio 2008 does not add the published application to the to start menu

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, clickonce

Visual Studio publish option does not seem to add the application to the start menu.

I just created one Windows form application and published it.(VS 2008)

I do see the published application in the window's Add/Remove programs but I do not see in in the start menu.

In the publish setting I have "the application is available offline as well (launchable from start menu) Checked.
[image]

Also where the published EXE file is supposed to go. Because I cannot find it either.

I am using windows XP.

Comment: Could you please test it on your side? I want to see if you can see the same thing. It should be a 2 minute test. just create an simple winform app and publish it.

Comment: I am starting to believe clickonce may have an issue with windows XP.

Comment: I've tested it in Visual Studio 2012. I created a Windows Form Application and Published it. It created a setup file on a specified directory(provided when publishing). Installed the setup file. Got the application in my start menu.

Comment: @codeSpy. Thanks for the test. Are you using windows XP or windows 7?

Comment: previously i tried on windows 8. But I've also tried on Visual Studio 2008 on Windows 7. In the publishing folder location give a specific location of a folder where your setup file will be created.Install that setup file.Problem may solve.

Comment: Hmm same procedure does not work for me, but I am on windows XP. I will test the above scenario when I get home(windows 7). Do you know where is the location of the created EXE file ?(setup should create an Exe)

Comment: Yes I know where the setup.exe file is. What I mean is after running the setup.exe, an EXE file should be created(For example WindowsApplication1.Exe) . I just cannot find it.

Comment: @S Nash -  
The setup file is actually a ClickOnce Installer. After installing it it created a ClickOnce(TestApplication) Application file that is in the following directory. C:\Users\codeSpy\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\TestApplication

Comment: Intetesting:
For Xp I can only see this 
C:\Documents and Settings\sanaghshineh\Application Data\Microsoft\Windows
Which does not have a Start Menu Subfolder. So you don't see a TestApplication.Exe file?

Comment: The "AppData" Folder is may be hidden inside sanaghshineh folder.

Comment: in XP it is Application Data\ and it is hidden. Again do you any exe file with the same name of your solution/project. I mean In your case TestApplication.Exe

Comment: There's no .exe file.

Comment: Ok I will test windows 7 as soon as I get home.

Comment: Yes, as expected everything works in windows 7. If you or someone add this as an answer I will accept.

Comment: I've posted the answer, you may check!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **Windows Form Application** follow the steps :

1. Right Click on the Project and click on **Publish**
2. Specify the location where you want to publish the application (any directory you want the **ClickOnce Installer** to be in) and click **Next**.
3. Select options from the radion buttons to specify How users will install the application (i.e. **From a CD-ROM or DVD-ROM**) and click **Next**.
4. Mention if you want the application to check for updates from a specific location and click **Next**.
5. Finally **Publish** the application by clicking **Finish**.

you'll get a **Setup** (**ClickOnce Installer**) file created in the specified directory(location specified in **step 1**)

Now **Install** it and enjoy your **Windows Form Application**. You'll get the application added in **Start Menu**.

**Note : This process has been tested in Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2008 and Windows 8 with Visual Studio 2012.**

Answer (score 1):

Publishing is not the same thing as installing.  After publishing (with the option of "available offline as well"), you should be able to launch the application from the publish location and then see the start menu item created after that.  Going forward, you can launch the application from the start menu.

Comment: In the publish location all I see is a Setup.EXE. This exe file only launches the app and after that,  I do not see the app in the start menu. Maybe because I use windows XP?

Comment: @SNash try setting a different installation folder.  I have that set on mine.  Also, I'm on Windows 7, but I wouldn't have thought that XP would be a problem.

Comment: For you does it create an item in the start menu?